# Using Postgresql as application server ( windows server )

Tags: windows, postgresql

I'm building an application to fill a database that I made with postgres.
It's possible to install postgresql on an existing windows Windows server ?
If yes can you give me a lead of how to do it ?
because I found on the internet that it's possible only with .NET Framework and that confuses me.
Just for information , this database should be updated from many users that have the access to the server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: enterprisedb makes a good installer http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgdownload

Comment: "becuase I found on the Internet". Link? What you're saying doesn't make sense. I think you might've got confused with nPgSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply install [PGAdmin](http://www.pgadmin.org/download/windows.php) on the mentioned server. It includes a copy of postgre-server. You can add users easily with the pgadmin interface or use the cmd if you prefer to add users using psql.

Btw: you **don't** need .NET stuff with this solution.

**Answers drawn together:**

- For administrative clients: just install pgadmin there as well.
- For software-clients (read/write) you don't need to install anything to connect to the server (your application should handle that) so no third-party.

If you want to move your current database to a new server you can either:

1. make a db-dump and load it using pgadmin (works with different pg versions)
2. [Do as listed here (console)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24783/move-postgresql-database-from-one-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bserver-to-another)

Comment: Thanks Swiggels  for your answer 
I'm a beginner, I have some questions if you can answer me:
should I Install something on the clients PCs?
its doable to migrate the database from my PC to the servers without any issue?
thanks in advance

Comment: If you ran the same database version on your pc, you can copy your data folder and it should work. (google for a tutorial) The clients can use pgadmin as administrative-client if needed. But if you speak of software-clients connecting to the database for read/write you don't need to install anything.

Comment: For moving your postgres-database read this: `http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24783/move-postgresql-database-from-one-server-to-another`. Or make a db-dump of your current database and load it with pgadmin.

Comment: Thanks a lot SWiggls that was very helpful

Answer (score 1):

On the server simply [use the installer](http://www.postgresql.org/download/windows/).

On client systems, it depends on how your app accesses the database. You might need to install the ODBC driver psqlODBC. You might need to bundle nPgSQL or PgJDBC with your app. Etc. It depends on the tools and languages you're using.

Note that PostgreSQL isn't a graphical user interface to a database. It has no form builder etc. It's just a database *engine* and you need an application to provide a user interface.

Comment: Thanks Craig Ringer I have already an application , localy ( On my Computer ) the database is perfectly connected with app, but when I'll put it on the server I have no Idea yet how it will be connected If you have a document or a lead for doing it that'll be perfect and nice of you.
thanks in advance

Comment: @xAmineX It uses TCP/IP, over the network. You need to configure `pg_hba.conf` to allow connections from other machines and change the Windows Firewall settings to allow the connection. You may also have to change `listen_addresses` in `postgresql.conf` to let the server accept connections. More detail is in the manual; look up `listen_addresses`, `pg_hba.conf`, and the "client authentication" chapter of the user manual.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to reply to me. I really appreciate it and I will definately look into the manual that you recommended, but which one ?  can you give me a link

Comment: @xAmineX https://www.google.com/?q=postgresql%20manual . Specifically, read http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html, `listen_addresses` in http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-connection.html and then http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/client-authentication.html . Also https://www.google.com/?q=add%20exception%20to%20windows%20firewall